# PostgreSQL кириллица

Tags: postgresql, кодировка, локаль

Я развернул в докере postgres командами:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
docker exec -it some-postgres bash
psql -U postgres
CREATE TABLE users(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, USERNAME TEXT, CHAT_ID INT, MESSAGE TEXT);
```

и подключил приложение которое записало данные в бд, но проблема в том что английские слова нормально отображаются а русские нет.

Первая запись на английском, вторая на русском.

Проверил через Windows консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И через Linux консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На разных устройствах.

В чём состоит проблема, как её решить и не допустить повторного возникновения.

Comment: Судя по формату кодирования кириллических символов, это приложение так в базу пишет. Попробуйте вставить русский текст запросом из psql.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev действительно все в порядке, просто я с приложения отправлял не сообщение от пользователя а перекодированный текст который на свой сервер уже отправлял. Спасибо что обратили внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том что я писал в бд данные с сервера, вместо обычного текста. Так что вина была на моей стороне а не на стороне бд.